# How to make get_posts to pull 2 levels of sub pages

Tags: wordpress

The template structure is:

- Product Index
- Product Category
- Product Single

They're all under Pages, not Posts. What I am trying to do is:

- Index page, get all page title from each category, and all the products inside each category.
- Category page, get all the products inside the category.
- Single page, just display the product

**Can anyone help to write the code for the index template please?**

Blow sample is the code for category template, which works well.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'none',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$postslist = get_posts($args);
foreach ($postslist as $post) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: You'll have to show some effort. What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I don't have a clue, it will be helpful if anyone can give me some info to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and create a type called `product`, for example.

Once your `product` type is registered, your theme should contain a template called `single-product.php`. See: [Template Hierarchy][http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png). This page will be displayed when a single product page is requested. This takes care of 3.

For your custom category, use [Custom Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). Once you've registered, for instance, `product-category` as you taxonomy for `product` post types, your theme can display archives for this on `taxonomy-product-category.php`. Again, see: [Template Hierarchy][http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png. This takes care of 2.

For 1. you'll need to query all taxonomies with something like [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories), setting the `taxonomy` argument to `product-category`. For each taxonomy, you need to use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get all the posts inside. This way you'll be able to display your products. Use this in `home.php`. Bear in mind that this may become quite slow, since you'll query the database N times, where N is the number of categories you have. You can optimize this later once you have a working model of what you're looking for.

Once you're up and running, I invite you to ask further more specific questions over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/